# game wmode issue when dealing with divs on top

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using starling for rendering so I must use wmode=direct in my application for it to work.

Having said that I need to show a box on top of flash under some circumstances. But when I show the box it appears on the back because of the wmode (works fine with opaque).

Is there any way I can show content on top of flash while I am in wmode=direct?

Comment: Zynga makes screenshot of Farmvile2 (that uses stage3d) and hides the hole swf. I think they makes screenshot in flash and pass it to js to insert into DOM. Another variant can be just hide the swf (set style.width=style.height=1px, or display:none or visibility:hidden)

Comment: Short answer: nope. Some browsers do support overlaying, but elements above the SWF tend to behave a little wonky. See here: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html

Comment: I used screenshots myself they're useful. But at times I need to show data while the game is working behind it. Say like a facebook like button on top of the game on loadings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try showing that box within SWF on 2D level, that level is by design above Stage3D content.

Comment: The box has a facebook like button to it. Which is essentially in a div.  Sadly no can do.